# Php webpage to turn on LED not working and just showing php code instead

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am new to RPi so sorry if this is a green question I’m trying to control the raspberry pi from a webpage so I am testing out with a single LED..
I installed Apache, php, and WiringPi successfully and got the “It works” page. But when I configure the code to turn on the GPIO pin for the LED it simply shows the code instead of turning on the LED. Any help is appreciated!

php code (in /var/www/html)

```
<?php

    system(“gpio -g mode 4 out”);
    system(“gpio -g write 4 1”);
```

Comment: Do you really have those curly quotes in there? `“`. Shouldn't those be regular quotes? `"`.

Comment: They are regular quotes on my Pi, just shows “ as I typed this question from my phone.. GPIO labelling is BCM here right?

Comment: Ah ok. Well, this is out of my league stuff. I am not the guy for this.

Comment: can you browse to this page in a regular browser? if so what do you see?

Comment: Yup. On my phone comes out exactly the same - just the code, doesn’t do anything to the LED

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)